# Принципиально ли использование BottomNavigationView?

Tags: android

Скажите пожалуйста есть ли какая-то принципиальная разница между использованием стандартного bottomnavigationview и создания своего?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю разница есть в нескольких аспектах:

1. Время на создание своего намного больше чем если взять то уже есть - продумывание логики, подвязка слушателей, создание макетов, возможные баги.
2. Кастомизировать проще свое чем чужое - если вы создаете что-то с нуля то вы знаете полностью как оно работает. Из этого вытекает что если например вам нужна какая-то новая фича менюшки то вы сможете ее добавить. Со стандартным виджетом так не получится - если нужна какая-то фича то либо ждать обновления, искать библиотеку или создать самому.

Посему если вам нужен просто функционал и ничего более, то я бы советовал просто взять стандартный виджет и не заморачиваться. Если же вам нужен какой-то супер-пупер макет для нижней менюшки то можно погуглить библиотеки, либо создать самому :)

Comment: Супер, спасибо!